# sqoop import oracle got stock at progress 0.0% for hours

Tags: sqoop

When sqoop import from oracle, we saw the following logs on yarn:

```
2022-05-10 04:52:13,351 INFO [IPC Server handler 12 on 44827] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1646802944907_44646_m_000000_0 is : 0.0
2022-05-10 04:52:43,421 INFO [IPC Server handler 20 on 44827] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1646802944907_44646_m_000000_0 is : 0.0
2022-05-10 04:53:13,487 INFO [IPC Server handler 18 on 44827] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1646802944907_44646_m_000000_0 is : 0.0
2022-05-10 04:53:43,556 INFO [IPC Server handler 22 on 44827] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Progress of TaskAttempt attempt_1646802944907_44646_m_000000_0 is : 0.0
....
```

The job got stuck at 0.0 for nearly one hour, and then ended with the error: ORA-01555: snapshot too old.

But this does not happen every time.
Our sqoop version is: 1.4.7-cdh6.3.1. Any one know what happened?